# How to scrape links from a a page with DOM & XPath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, curl, hyperlink

I have a page scraped with curl and am looking to grab all of the links with a certain id. As far as I can tell the best way to do this is with dom and xpath. The bellow code grabs a large number of the urls, but cuts many of them off and grabs text that is not a url.

$curl_scraped_page is the page scraped with curl.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($curl_scraped_page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");
```

Am I on the right track? Do I just need to mess with the "/html/body//a" xpath syntax or do I need to add more to capture the id element?

Comment: What do you mean by links with a certain id? Links whose ID is on a particular list?

Comment: for example: <link id="www-core-css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/cssbin/www-core-vflQPQ9rK.css"> I do not just want "http://s.ytimg.com/yt/cssbin/www-core-vflQPQ9rK.css" I also want id="www-core-css"

Comment: @user586011: You are just selection any `a` anchor inside `body`. You don't know if it's a link to an outside resource, or just an inside anchor. Plus, once you select the desired elements you need to extract their properties through the proper DOM method (attributes, string value, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way and you'll have onyl `a` tags which have an `id` and `href` :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($curl_scraped_page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$hrefs = $xpath->query('//a[@href][@id]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($curl_scraped_page);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$processed_links = array();

foreach ($links as $link)
{
    if ($link->hasAttribute('id') && $link->hasAttribute('href'))
    {
        $processed_links[$link->getAttribute('id')] = $link->getAttribute('href');
    }
}
```

This is the solution regarding your question.

Answer (score 0):

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
foreach($html->find('#www-core-css') as $e) echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is combining 2 following classes to pull information from another website:

Pull info from any HTML tag, contents or tag attribute: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Easy to handle curl, supports POST requests: https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

Example:

```
include('path/to/curl.php');
include('path/to/simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

$curl = new Curl;
$html = str_get_html($curl->get($url)); //full HTML of website
$linksWithSpecificID = $html->find('a[id=foo]'); //returns array of elements
```

Check Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual from the upper link for the manipulation with HTML data.